# VBA Edit 3rd line of a Text File

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a text file (c:\temp\temp.txt) and I want to be able to use VBA to edit the file and and wipe out the 3rd row of string data (it's variable so I don't know what it will say) but keep the rest of the rows of text intact.

I've been trying to figure it out, it seems like I have to open the file, save the entire file as a string, then close and reopen the file and edit the string and save?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you are, then take a look at our VBA docs - reading a file (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/990/scripting-filesystemobject/3221/reading-a-text-file-using-a-filesystemobject#t=201608242132490774474) and writing a file (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/990/scripting-filesystemobject/3223/writing-to-an-existing-file-with-filesystemobject#t=201608242132490774474)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pseudocode is pretty much what you need to do.  I'd personally split on a newline and write individual lines back:

```
Private Sub KillLineThree(filepath As String)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Dim lines() As String
        With .OpenTextFile(filepath)
            lines = Split(.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
            .Close
        End With

        Dim i As Long
        With .CreateTextFile(filepath)
            For i = LBound(lines) To UBound(lines)
                If i <> 2 Then .WriteLine lines(i)
            Next
            .Close
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

as a shorter a bit overkill version you can use Excel

```
Workbooks.Open "c:\temp\temp.txt"
Rows(3).Delete
DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Creative solution! I like it!